# PowerShell ListView set selected item by index

Tags: powershell

I'd like to programmatically select an item in a ListView box using an index:

Something like: `$ListViewBox.SelectedIndex = 1`

This doesn;t exist though....

Is the only way around this to look up the actual text for the "FocusedItem" method?

I was sort of hoping I could set the selected index to -1 to remove all or current selections.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not exactly the answer, but found a way to do what I needed:

```
If ($ListView.FocusedItem -ne $null) {
    $ListView.FocusedItem.Focused = $false
}
If ($ListView.SelectedItems.Count -ne 0) {
$Listview.SelectedItems[0].Selected = $false
}
```